# Spring OAUTH2 JWT Mapping user permissions to scopes

Tags: json, web-services, jwt, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I have a question concerning the mapping of my user permissions to access token scopes in spring JWT, in fact, when I am mapping all user permissions to the accesstoken scopes as follows:

```
public class AuthorityTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        final ImmutableMap<String, Object> additionalInfo = ImmutableMap
                .builder()
                .put("authorities", user.getAuthorities())
                .build();
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setScope(user.getPermissions());
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

and when I want to test this in my WebService by `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')` and `#oauth2.hasScope('XXXXX')")` annotation.  It does not work because the checking is based on client scopes rather than user accesstoken scopes? Is there a way, for using access token scopes (which represents my permissions user) rather than client scopes by using the `#oauth2.hasScope('XXXXX')` annotation? How can I do that?